# Bootstrap tooltip changes its position on 2nd click?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 for my website. I have used bootstrap provided tooltip which I have been displaying on image click.
But the problem I am facing is: when I click the first time on the image it works properly, but when I click on 2nd time its position changes. I have attached two images which I get on 1st click and on 2nd click. Please provide solution for it.

I'm adding coding which I'm using .

```
$('#trypersonalLink').tooltip({
    title : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
    placement : "right",
    trigger : "click",
    html : true,
    container : 'body'
}).on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
    $('.tooltip.right').css('margin-left', '-86px');
    $('.tooltip-inner').css({
        'max-width':'370px',
        'width':'445px'
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happens :

1. You click on the button
2. The tooltip is loaded with default size, its position is JS-calculated (based on size)
3. `shown.bs.tooltip` is triggered
4. You change the tooltip size
5. Another click on the button
6. The tooltip is reloaded, but its position is re-calculated, based on its new size !

That's why your tooltip hasn't the same position on the first load only.

To fix this, you should avoid setting `margin`, `max-width` and `width` in `shown.bs.tooltip`. Use CSS for it !

```
$('#trypersonalLink').tooltip({
  title : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
  placement : "right",
  trigger : "click",
  html : true,
  container : 'body'
});
```

```
.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 370px;
}
```

---

**Bonus**

If you only want to increase this tooltip size, but not the other ones, you can specify a different container in your options :

```
$('#trypersonalLink').tooltip({
  title : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
  placement : "right",
  trigger : "click",
  html : true,
  container : '#extended'
});

$('#trypersonalLink2').tooltip({
  title : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
  placement : "right",
  trigger : "click",
  html : true,
  container : 'body'
});
```

```
#extended .tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 370px;
}
```

[**Bootply**](http://bootply.com/112951)

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to set answers as "Accepted" (green tick) is you thinks your problem is solved (this is valid for your 15 non-closed questions)

Comment: Hey Zessx ticked green but here is one more thing position is now fine but it is accepting width on alternate clicks :(

Comment: I don't understand what's happening. Can you describe the problem ?

Comment: Okay I used what u above mentioned.Now when I'm clicking on image tooltip is locating properly (position is perfect now).What is happening now when i do  my first click on image tooltip appears and takes max-width of 370px but on 2nd click it does not take this max-width and on 3rd click its takes this max-width .....So its a kind of fluctuation happening here..

Comment: Have you updated your JS ? (remove the content of `.on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {}`)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47311/discussion-between-kingisback-and-zessx)